# manim does not create an output file

Tags: python, manim

If I run

```
python -m manimlib scene.py ket_bra
```

My scene renders fine into the interactive viewer, but I don't get any output file, the terminal prints the following

```
ManimGL v1.6.1
[13:55:48] INFO     Using the default configuration file, which you can modify in `c:\users\miika\manim\manimlib\default_config.yml`                                                                                  config.py:323
           INFO     If you want to create a local configuration file, you can create a file named `custom_config.yml`, or run `manimgl --config`                                                                      config.py:324
           WARNING  You may be using Windows platform and have not specified the path of `temporary_storage`, which may cause OSError. So it is recommended to specify the `temporary_storage` in the config file     config.py:290
                    (.yml)

(process:3548): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 13:55:49.613: Unexpectedly, UWP app `Clipchamp.Clipchamp_2.3.0.0_neutral__yxz26nhyzhsrt' (AUMId `Clipchamp.Clipchamp_yxz26nhyzhsrt!App') supports 46 extensions but has no verbs
```

If I add the parameter -p to the command then the interactive window remains blank and doesn't render the scene and in no case do I get an output file which is what I'm looking for and the terminal output is the same as before. Also if it's of note the background is grey, even tho it appears to be black in all samples that I can find. I have absolutely no idea what's going on as I can't find anybody else with a similar issue. I'm using windows 10 and v1.6.1 of 3b1b manim. The scene in this case is as follows (though this issue appears regardless of what the scene is)

```
from manimlib import *

class ket_bra(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        ket_q0 = Tex(r"|q_0\rangle")
        ket_0 = Tex(r"|0\rangle")
        ket_1 = Tex(r"|1\rangle")

        ket_0_v2 = Tex(r"|0\rangle")
        ket_1_v2 = Tex(r"|1\rangle")

        ket_0_v3 = Tex(r"""|0\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
                            1\\
                            0
                            \end{pmatrix}""")
        ket_1_v3 = Tex(r"""|1\rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
                            0\\
                            1
                            \end{pmatrix}""")

        bra_kets = VGroup(ket_q0, ket_0, ket_1).arrange(RIGHT, buff=1)
        v_bra_kets = VGroup(ket_0_v2, ket_1_v2).arrange(RIGHT, buff=1.5)
        bra_kets_def = VGroup(ket_0_v3, ket_1_v3).arrange(RIGHT, buff=1.5)
        
        self.play(Write(ket_q0), Write(ket_0), Write(ket_1))
        self.wait(0.5)
        self.play(FadeOut(ket_q0))
        self.play(Transform(ket_0, ket_0_v2), Transform(ket_1, ket_1_v2))
        self.wait(1)
        self.play(Transform(ket_0, ket_0_v3), Transform(ket_1, ket_1_v3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed the problem, without fixing the problem, I just switched to the community edition of manim and it works exactly as intended, so if you encounter the same problem and you're using 3b1b manim version, I reccomend just switching to the community version of manim, they are mostly functionally equivalent, but the community edition appears to be less buggy at least for me. Here's a super easy installation guide for it https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/installation/windows.html

However, I won't mark this as the best answer, because I didn't really solve the problem, and I still get the following warning and have no idea what it is. However, it appears to not affect functionality so it's fine, lol.

Answer (score 0):

#### Windows Solution

1. Create TempLatex directory in C drive
2. Find manimlib/default_config.yml in the manim (manimgl version) directory and open it with a text editor
3. Modify line 18: before: temporary_storage: "" after: temporary_storage: "C:/TempLatex "
4. Save

From:
https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/1661#issuecomment-996575974